# Disable/enable all elements in div

Tags: jquery, html

How to make quick disabling/enabling of all the elements in any div (inputs, links and jQ Buttons)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Links do not have a "disabled" property, so you'll have to work a bit harder.

```
$('#my_div').find(':input').prop('disabled', true);
$('#my_div a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

To re-activate:

```
$('#my_div').find(':input').prop('disabled', false);
$('#my_div a').unbind("click");
```

The [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector *Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements.*

Also see http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: The true parameter in `prop('disabled')` is redundant. It's not like the `attr()` function

Comment: FYI I just learned a few minutes ago the 'disabled' property does not set as expected with simply `prop('disabled')` whereas checked and selected do. `prop('disabled')` should set the property per their documentation. I smell a 1.6.3 bug fix ;)

Answer (score 8):

```
$('#my_div').find('*').prop('disabled',true);
```

To re-enable, simply use `.removeProp()` http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/

Comment: prop('disabled',true) as prop('disabled') just returns value

Comment: @jacek - good eye. this is a jquery bug, as it behaves as expected with other properties. As you can see in their 1.6 changelog, the expected behavior is to set the property not return the value: http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/03/jquery-16-released/

Comment: What's with the `find('*')` over `$('#my_div *')`? And as mentioned by [karim79](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961678/disable-enable-all-elements-in-div/6961782#6961782), links are unaffected by the `disabled` attribute, perhaps a flaw in the semantics of OPs question, or perhaps a misunderstanding of what `disabled` is used for.

Comment: `find('*')` is more than **twice as fast** as `$('#my_div *')`. Here's some benchmarking evidence: http://jsperf.com/selector-specific-vs-find

Comment: To re-enable use $('#my_div').find('*').prop('disabled',false);

Answer (score 6):

```
$('div').find('input, a, button').prop('disabled', true);
```

or maybe all:

```
$('div *').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: -1 you should be using `prop()` instead of `attr()` for properties such as "disabled", "checked", "selected", etc.