# How to disable & enable all contents of a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to disable all elements of Div tag. I get success on input types. But not able to disable links.
I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6961709/1624583), but it is not working. 
Here is the code I have tried(But it works for input only):

```
 $('#EditorRows *').attr('disabled', true);
```

I know disable for input types but I want to achieve that type of mechanism for links.

> **1st PartialView Code:**

```
<div id="Part2">
<div id="EditorRows">
<%= Html.ActionLink("Add another...", "Add", null, new { id = "addItem" }) %>
<%Html.RenderPartial("_InsertServices", Model);%>
</div>
<div id="DontAppend">
<input type="button" id="btnEdit" value="Edit" hidden="hidden"/>
<input type="button" id="btnDone" value="Done" />
</div>
</div>
```

> **2nd PartialView**

```
<div class="EditorRow">
<% using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("services"))
{ %>
<table id="table1">
<tr><td>
NOS:</td><td>
<%:Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Id,(SelectList)ViewData["crmServiceType"] as SelectList,"---")%>
</td>
<td>
Comment:</td><td>
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Comment, new { size = "20" })%></td>
<td>
<a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<% } %>
</div>
```

> **script:**

```
    $("#addItem").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) { $("#EditorRows").append(html); }
            });
            return false;
        });

        $("a.deleteRow").live("click", function () {
            $(this).parents("div.EditorRow:first").remove();
            return false;
        });

$('#btnDone').click(function () {
      $('#EditorRows *').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    $('#btnEdit').click(function () {
      $('#EditorRows *').attr('disabled', false);
    }
```

Comment: disable? what do you mean. It's only input fields who support this attribute. You can hide the div instead.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `<a>` elements don't have a `disabled` property, but I might be wrong. Do you want to grey them out, have nothing happen when you click them, hide them or something else?

Comment: @h2ooooooo, i want that nothing happen when I click on it.

Comment: then make cursor :none

Comment: @TommySorensen, I dont want to hide, Yes I can fadeto it but I want it to be away from clicking.

Comment: @djIT By default nothing happens when you click a div. Does anything happen when you click it now?

Comment: what i know is disable is for form elements

Comment: u can use prevent default

Comment: can you post the html?  maybe a jsfiddle?

Comment: Do we all know the difference between properties and attributes? Why are we changing the attributes in places when properties will do? it is slower and puts you in a bind if you ever need state data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$('#EditorRows').find('a').each(function(){
   $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
});
```

**Update**

To disable :

```
$('#EditorRows').find('a').bind('click', false);
```

To enable :

```
$('#EditorRows').find('a').unbind('click', false);
```

Answer (score 3):

To disable links use this

```
$('div a').unbind('click');
```

Ore in your case:

```
$('#btnDone').click(function () {
    var $rows = $('#EditorRows');
    $rows.find('input, select, textarea').attr('disabled', true);
    $rows.find('a').unbind('click');
}
```

Comment: Yes the cursor is still a pointer but when you click nothing should happend

Comment: It is happening that's the problem.

Comment: Then your are not running the code the correct place. Can you please give us more information about how you code looks like?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25694/discussion-between-tommysorensen-and-djit)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').find(':input').prop('disabled',true);//this line will this able all inputs including buttons.
$('div').find('a').each(function(){
   $(this).removeAttr('href');
   $(this).unbind('click');
});//this will take care of the links
```

I think this will take care of the problem

Answer (score 0):

use off method of jquery.

```
$('#Yourdiv a').off('click');

$('#yourDiv').find('input').attr('disabled',true);
```

or else simple is just return false when anchor clicked.

```
$('#Yourdiv a').on('click',function(e)
                  {
                   return false;  // or e.preventDefault();
                  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for input only because they have `disable` attribute. To disable link try

if you want just to delete the link redirect.

```
$("#youdivname").find('a').removeAttr('href')
```

This will active it again :

```
$("#yourdivname").find('a').attr('href','link')
```

where `link` is the redirect.

Comment: I want a toggle type of effect. Enable & Disable.

Comment: Explain better. When do you want to fire this event? We can answer you better.

Comment: I want to just disable clicking of links.

Comment: dude , you posted only some input, neither the anchors , we don't know when you're gonna fire the code, neither where.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution that came to mind, but it does not pretend to be elegant
http://jsbin.com/icijox/4/edit

Comment: What do you mean, nothing working, i just see, all done. I made base for your, you can change this code for your own purpose. Just click "Run with JS" and open Console tab to see reaction

Comment: It is giving me worning: Line 1: var state = 'enable';  --- Unexpected ' '.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Cd9TV/ maybe on resource its better to see my script in action